# Virtual base classes order of creation

Tags: c++, constructor, multiple-inheritance, virtual-inheritance, order-of-execution

I have the following problem:

```
struct A1 {
    A1() { std::cout << "A1, "; }
};

struct A2 {
    A2() { std::cout << "A2, "; }
};

struct AA1 : virtual A1,  A2 {
    AA1() { std::cout << "AA1, "; }
};

struct AA2 : A1, virtual A2 {
    AA2(){ std::cout << "AA2, "; }
};

struct B : AA1, virtual AA2 {
    B() { std::cout << "B "; }
};

int main() {
    B b;
}
```

When you run this code, the answer is:

> A1 A2 A1 AA2 A2 AA1 B

I want to understand where is the first `A1` created.

I know the rule that the virtual classes are called before non - virtual classes but that first A1 is the problem that is bothering me.

Comment: Can you please improve your code formatting for easy read?

Comment: Virtual classes aren't "called". You cannot "call a class". Rather, *objects are initialized*.

Comment: You are right, I made a mistake. Thank you for the explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first `A1` results from the initialization of the (virtual) base of the (non-virtual) base `AA1` of `B`.

All the virtual bases of `B` are initialized first, and they are, in order, `A1`, `A2` and `AA2`. (The initialization of `AA2` results in the output `A1 AA2`.) Then come the direct bases, of which there is only one, `AA1` (whose initialization prints `A2 AA1`), and finally the class itself, printing `B`. All the virtual bases come first, and then only the remaining non-virtual ones.

Comment: Thank you so much. This really helps me a lot. I was struggling to understand this virtual functions. They were the only that I couldn't understand and this answer just helped me so much.

Comment: The first `A1` actually results from the virtual base of `AA1`, not from the non-virtual base of `AA2` (which is actually the second `A1`). You can visualize this by adding a parameter to the constructor indicating from where they are "called".

Comment: @DropFuriosPolaris: My original explanation was wrong; please see the updated result, thanks to Holt's correction.

Answer (score 2):

`B` has three virtual base classes: `A1`, `A2` and `AA2`, and according to their order of appearance, it will initialize them in this order.

The first `A1` and `A2` you see are the initializing of the virtual base `A1` and `A2`, but the last virtual base `AA2` has a non-virtual base `A1`, so before constructing `AA2`, you'll need to construct another `A1`, which is why you have another `A1` before `AA2`.

You can visualize this by running the following snippet:

```
#include <iostream>

struct A1 {
    A1(const char *s) { std::cout << "A1(" << s << ")\n"; }
};

struct A2 {
    A2(const char *s) { std::cout << "A2(" << s << ")\n"; }
};

struct AA1 : virtual A1,  A2 {
    AA1(const char *s) : A1("AA1"), A2("AA1") { std::cout << "AA1(" << s << ")\n"; }
};

struct AA2 : A1, virtual A2 {
    AA2(const char *s) : A1("AA2"), A2("AA2") { std::cout << "AA2(" << s << ")\n"; }
};

struct B : AA1, virtual AA2 {
    B() : A1("B"), A2("B"), AA1("B"), AA2("B") { std::cout << "B()\n"; }
};

int main() {
    B b;
}
```

This will output:

```
A1(B)
A2(B)
A1(AA2)
AA2(B)
A2(AA1)
AA1(B)
B()
```

You can also notice that this code gives you warning because:

- I put `A1` before `A2` in `AA2`'s constructor, but `A2` will be initialized before `A1` (because it is a virtual base and `A1` is not).
- I put `AA1` before `AA2` in `B`'s constructor, but `AA2` will be initialized first (same reason).